# Can "gcloud auth login" remember me for at least a day?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I run "gcloud auth login" and then do some stuff, but after some time (~1hr or so) I have to run it again because otherwise I am not authenticated.

Is it normal? Can gcloud authentication remember me for a longer period?

Comment: Are you doing any API calls?

Comment: Not sure, which API calls you mean. I am simply trying to git push/pull origin.

Answer (score 6):

It's not expected behavior, no. As per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/gcloud/#gcloud.auth)

> Your credentials do not expire (i.e. you should not need to re-run
>   this command), but you can repeat this process as many times as you'd
>   like to add more accounts.

I'd recommend making sure that you're not clearing or deleting any of the following directories, as this is where everything is stored:

> All credential information is stored in the directory
>   $CLOUDSDK_CONFIG/credentials (or %CLOUDSDK_CONFIG%\credentials on
>   Windows), where CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=$HOME/.config/gcloud on Linux and Mac,
>   and %APPDATA%\gcloud on Windows.

Also, try listing and setting the appropriate accounts with the commands recommended on the linked document.

Comment: After re-installing the SDK it seems to work. However, the first time I do e.g. git push I get an error: "fatal: Authentication failed for ...", and immediately after I repeat the same command and it works fine.

Comment: Documentation no longer mentions no expiration... at least on that link. I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if an admin has enabled a session duration.

Maybe you need to set it to be longer here: https://admin.google.com/ac/security/reauth/admin-tools

Comment: Ours is set to `never require reauthentication` and yet my creds expire after a couple hours.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by killing all my Google sessions in my browser (by deleting all of my Google cookies)